# How to export an array or ordered table in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am building a 300x300 model with each grid cell being 10m. I used the sprout command to generate 1 turtle in each patch. The turtles perform some procedures and I keep the result in their original patch and die. I need to export this generated result which is stored in the patch. Does anyone know how I can export an array with the correct spatial distribution of the patch parameter? Or maybe an ordered table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: export-world will have the information you need, or simply export both the patch coordinates and the variables you want, it doesn't need to be exported as an array, all you need are the values that indicate the position, the file doesn't need to be in that particular order

Comment: Thanks so much JenB. Sorry for the beginner's question, how do I export the patch coordinates and the variable I want? Could you indicate a model that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of a run, you can simply use the export commands in the menu, the most relevant is `export-world` but that will include other information.

If you just want to export specific informaiton, have a look at the File Output Example in the NetLogo models library. In your case, you will want to export patch information including the variables `pxcor` and `pycor` as they are the positions (or cell indices for the array)